# git verify-pack and number of blobs

Tags: git, bash

I am looking at this line:

```
# list all objects including their size, sort by size, take top 10
objects=`git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | grep -v chain | sort -k3nr | head`
```

It says that 10 items will be taken. But I don't see 10 anywhere. What if I want 40 instead, where should that go in the above line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`head` outputs 10 lines by default. For 40, you could write

```
objects=`git verify-pack ... | head -n 40`
```